# Plotting by quantile in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot `foo ~ bar`. However, I don't want to look at the exact data, I'd rather break `bar` into say quantiles, and plot `mean(foo)` for every quantile (so my final plot will have 5 data points). Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at `?quantile`?

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible by having a look at [**How to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for us to help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 foo <- rnorm(100)
 bar <- rnorm(100)

  mn.foo.byQ10bar <- tapply(foo, cut(bar, quantile(bar, (0:5)/5, na.rm=TRUE)), mean)

> mn.foo.byQ5bar
 (-3.31,-0.972] (-0.972,-0.343]  (-0.343,0.317]   (0.317,0.792]    (0.792,2.71] 
     0.13977839      0.03281258     -0.18243804     -0.14242885     -0.01696712 

 plot(mn.foo.byQ5bar)
```

This is a fairly standard task and Harrell's Hmisc package's `cut2` function has a nice gr= argument that lets you do this by just specifying an integer for the number of groups. I also like it because the intervals from the cut operation are left-closed instead of R default for right-closed.

Comment: DWin, could you briefly tell (if you're aware of) what's the idea of such a plot? Plotting quantiles against mean of data within each quantile range. I can't think of the idea behind it...

Comment: Some people seem to like barplots more than scatterplots. (I'm not in that category and if the numbers of observations exceeds a few hundred would use a hexbin plot or a 2d density plot for continuous by continuous comparisons.) This barplot approach might support visualizing a 4 degree of freedom chi-square GOF test (again not what I would advice), where the independent variable was grouped by quintile and the corresponding foo-means were bar-heights.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine a lot of these lines into more concise code, but here it is broken down

```
# Sample Data: 
x <- 1:100;   y <- rnorm(x)

# Number Of Groups
N <- 5

# quantiles
Q.y <- quantile(y, probs=seq(0, 1, length=(N+1)))
Q.x <- quantile(x, probs=seq(0, 1, length=N))

# means of y by quantile
means.y <- c(by(y, cut(y, Q.y), mean))

# plot them 
qplot(Q.x, means.y)
```